# Difference of passing sessions to subtransactions

Tags: python, sql, database, transactions, sqlalchemy

I don't get the difference of using subtransactions and passing sessions using sqlalchemy. Can anyone explain the difference between the two approaches outlined below?

Let us  assume we have a `method_a` calling `method_b`

```
def method_a(session):
   method_b(session)

def method_b(session):
    session.add(SomeObject())
```

Furthermore I have two possible context managers. The first one is for passing sessions

```
@contextmanager
def pure_session(session):
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
```

and the second one for passing subtransactions

```
@contextmanager
def transactional_session(session, nested, subtransactions):
    session.begin(nested=nested, subtransactions=subtransactions)
    try:
        yield session
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        session.commit()
```

What is now the difference between the following executions?

```
session = Session()
with pure_session:
    method_a(session)
session.close()
```

and

```
session = Session(autocommit=True):
with transactional_session(session=session, nested=False, subtransactions=True):
     method_a(session)
session.close()
```

Note that I didn't set `nested` to True. Hence there are no savepoints. Furthermore autocommit was set to True for the second case. I don't quite get whether I should work with passing sessions in this context or using transactions. As far as I know sessions are more advanced connections keeping track of non-commited (flushed) changes. On the other hand subtransactions handle transactions taking place within a sub function. But what is the difference of these two approaches (if I set nested=False)? And what is a better design?

I think of subtransactions being a cleaner way since there will be less shadow operations.

(I know using subtransactions shouldn't be set to True. However, I want to make sure the whole process is set back to it's initial state once something failed during execution).

Thank you in advance